# Some doubts related Microsoft SQL Server bigint

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I have the following doubt related to **Microsoft SQL Server**. If a **bigint** column has a value as **0E-9**, does it mean that this cell can contain value with 9 decimal digits or what?

Comment: Unclear please add more details, `0e-9` (zero not oh as you have which is invalid) is `0` ...

Answer (score 1):

```
BIGINT:   -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 TO 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
INT:      -2,147,483,648 TO 2,147,483,647
SMALLINT: -32,768 TO 32,767
TININT:    0 TO 255
```

These are for storing non-decimal values. You need to use `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` to store values shuch as `112.455`. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1.

`OE-9` isn't `NUMERIC`or `INTEGER` value. It's a `VARCHAR` unless you are meaning something else like scientific notation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, the value would be stored as an integer. Any decimal amounts will be dropped off and only values to the left of the decimal will be kept (no rounding).

More specifically, bigint stores whole numbers between -2^63 and 2^63-1.